# GitHub working on separate branches but same class. How would we merge this?

Tags: java, git, github, merge, branch

We are currently 2 people working on a project. We use github, we have one master branch. And 2 sub branches for each developer. So in total we have 3 branches with master.

Lets say we have a file hello.class. Both developer makes changes to the file in their respective branches. If I now push and merge my sub-branch with master. The other sub-branch falls behind and needs to pull master, and then rebase it with hes sub-branch.

The problem now occours, because if he rebase's masters changes, he overwrites he's work in hello.class. How would we go about solving this problem? Is there a way to pull master, and then automerge changes into the sub-branch without overwriting the work done in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merging is half of what git is *for*.  If the changes conflict, git will abort the merge/rebase and ask you to fix them up before continuing; if the changes are in different parts of the file, git will do the merge itself.  You have to go out of your way to lose work.

Comment: I now changed a variabel, merge to master and pushed it. The other part pulled master, and merged it into he's sub-branch. No errors on the merge. Why not? He's variable just changed to what I typed. And I believe it should not? Because it should report a merge conflict because he's variable got changed? What if he did not want that variable to change?

Comment: then he shouldn't have merged?  the _whole point_ of merging is to get new code changes; why would git throw an error every time it saw one?  if he didn't change the same lines that you did, there won't be a conflict, because git can combine the changes automatically.

Comment: Aha, so if I change a line, and he changes the same line. There will be an error. But if I change a line, and he's line is the same as the old master line. It will automerge? Nice! Lets say we got an error, what would i open to resolve it?

Comment: you'd just edit the file, and git would have added markers like `<<<<<<<` around the conflicting areas.  you can also use `git mergetool` if you're familiar with a merge utility already, and git will open each conflicting file in sequence for you.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't overwrite changes. It merges them when you do a rebase (you could also do a merge, i.e. `git merge master`). If you both change the same line of code then git will get confused and ask you to fix merge conflicts. But if you didn't change the exact same line, git is smart enough to merge the changes.

I'm assuming that you are committing .java files as you shouldn't be committing .class files.

Comment: Would this approach be correct for 2 sub-branches? 

creates branch test.
Changes some line of code.
commits changes.
push changes
git merge test

Then the other part working on branch test2.
git checkout master
git git pull
git checout test2
git rebase master

Now the file test1 changed is also changed on test2? Why, what did we do wrong? If lets say we wanted to merge not overwrite?